# Add </ to text without HTML thinking it's a tag

Tags: html

I want to write `</Hello` (with a bracket at the end), but HTML thinks it is a tag. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an **HTML Escape** for both:

- the ***less than*** character (**<**) which is... `&lt;`
- the ***greater than*** character {**>**) which is... `&gt;`

This will give you:

#### `&lt;/Hello&gt;`

which will render in the browser as:

#### </Hello>

---

Other useful **HTML Escapes** include:

- `&` => `&amp;`
- `"` => `&quot;`
- `'` => `&#39;`
- `<` => `&lt;`
- `>` => `&gt;`
- `[SPACE]` => `&nbsp;`
- `[NEWLINE]` => `&#13;`

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

Answer (score 4):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<` on html.

```html
<p>&lt;/Hello</p>
```